# How can I convert a C-key code into a 'normal' key code?

Tags: key-bindings, keystrokes, events

#### Background

With jumping packages like Ace and Avy, you can start a function, provide a query char, and then jump to somewhere based on further input. (Lately I've preferred Avy, but that's irrelevant here.)

I have had both bound to `C-' C-;` (with other jumping functions bound to the home row) so that I can just hold control and fire off the sequence. It's very distracting though to have to lift my finger off control to input a 'plain' character for `read-char` to read.

#### Question

How can I strip all modifier keys off a `read-char`-returned key code?

Comment: For a-z you can likely just do: `(string (+ (read-char) 96))`

You'll need to do some more sanity checking for anything you use though, also you'll need to handle `C-g` which you can likely with `with-local-quit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `event-basic-type`.  E.g. `(event-basic-type ?\C-;)` returns `?;`.

If you want to only stop the `control` modifier but keep the other modifiers (e.g. the shift modifier), then you can try something like:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(defun my-strip-control (event)
  (event-convert-list
   (append (cl-set-difference (event-modifiers event)
                              '(control click))
           (list (event-basic-type event)))))
```

Comment: This is good enough for my use case (and actually answers my question more strictly than I meant it) so I'll still accept if the following can't be done: is it possible to keep 'Shift' as a modifier key? That is, to convert `\C-L -> L`?

Comment: In Elisp, `?\C-l` and `?\C-L` are one and the same.

Comment: Is that really true? Because I have `C-s` bound to `isearch` and `C-S` (i.e. `C-S-s`) bound to `helm-swoop`.

Comment: Details matter: `?\C-l` and `?\C-L` are one and the same, but `?\C-L` and `?\C-\S-l` are different.