# How are normal characters inserted into emacs?

Tags: key-bindings

**A trivial Problem?**

I have somehow managed to set `c`and a few other keys to prefix-commands, meaning they wait for a further input (like e.g. `C-x` does) and so I cannot actually type the letter `c` when `yas-minor-mode` is enabled.
See here for more details:
[Remove strange keybindings from YASnippet](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16712/remove-strange-keybindings-from-yasnippet)

I like `yas-minor-mode`, however, and so would like to remove these prefix keys so the normal character `c` on my keyboard to actually insert a `c` into emacs when in `yas-minor-mode`.

I had tried removing yas-minor-mode and reinstalling - no luck.
I tried to redfine the keys with things like `global-set-key` - again no joy.

Here is another similar looking questions, which made me think I could use the function `basic-event-type` - but I now think it isn't correct - plus my version 24.5 emacs doesn'T even seem to have that function.

[How can I convert a C-key code into a 'normal' key code?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12326/how-can-i-convert-a-c-key-code-into-a-normal-key-code)

Comment: "I have somehow managed to set `c`[...] they wait for a further unput" - this probably due to a snippet with a [`# binding:` header](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#org67f4e69) grabbing these keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just bind the key that corresponds to the character that you want to insert to `self-insert-command`.  E.g., assuming that the variable holding the keymap you want is `yas-minor-mode-map`, and if `c` is the character:

```el
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map "c" 'self-insert-command)
```

Or for the `global-map`:

```el
(global-set-key  "c" 'self-insert-command)
```

Comment: This is perhaps a "Band-Aid"™, as the behavior described by the original poster should not be happening out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me - I had been looking for a function like 'self-insert-command', but as an Elisp beginner I didn't find it.
@lawlist - As I had mentioned in my post, I introduced the error myself after playing around with saome other key binding - it wasn't a problem "out of the box". If I get further issues after Drew's fix, I will update the post here!

Comment: You can find `self-insert-command` by using `C-h k` and typing any key that inserts the char that it names. So if self-insertion still works for `a`, for instance, then `C-h k a` will tell you that `a` is bound to `self-insert-command`.

Comment: `C-h k` was my 'find of the day' - although somewhat bittersweet... one has to feel quite ashamed for not having known it in the first place!

Comment: `C-h C-h` is your friend, and will teach you about `C-h k`, `C-h m`, `C-h v`, and more.